# Imported FBX animation looks strange on action editor

Tags: .fbx

I made a rig and a set of animations in a Blend file and then lost the file. 
I do have a FBX file that I exported with the mesh, rig and animations.

I've managed to import it into a new Blend file, but I have the following problems:

- Instead of displaying the bone names, it displays the X Y Z Location, Quaternion and Scale for each bone.
- It made a keyframe for every single frame in the animation.

Is there a way I can fix this to get the file back to an editable state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "keyframe for every single frame in the animation" part of your question "is a feature, not a bug": That is how Blender outputs an FBX.

[image]

In object mode, select your armature. I imagine you may not be able to see it unless you turn on Xray.

[image]

Now go into pose mode and Blender's Animation screen set up.... or, I find this easier, anyway:

[image]

Your dope sheet will show you which bones in the armature have actions keyframed to them. Although Blender creates a keyframe for each frame, it does not create one for each bone -- only those bones that have actions associated with them.

In the NLA editor, you can turn this set of keyframes into an action strip, and you can B box select and simplify.... but it is still less elegant than what you undoubtedly had in your original Blender file.

Regarding names and axis... does your file look like this?

[image]

If that's what you are seeing, you can turn them off under the Armature panel.... but I have seen weird issues with some FBXes (more often scaling and orientation than naming)... and frankly I typically just hack at them until I get what I want... That is not really an answer... just what I do.

best
rg